# Error.getStackTrace() returns a string unparseable in flashdevelop?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, stack-trace, flash-cs4, flashdevelop

Accessing a string created by an Error's getStackTrace function is resulting in very unusual behaviour in the FlashDevelop IDE.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main():void
        {
            print("Start");

            var err:Error = new Error();
            var stack:String = err.getStackTrace();

            print(stack);
            // also occurs when this is replaced with stack.length or stack[0]

            print("End");
        }

        private function print(input:*):void
        {
            trace(input);
            trace("---");
        }
    }
}
```

When run in flash CS4 that outputs

```
Start
---
Error
    at Main()
---
End
---
```

But when run in FlashDevelop (replacing `trace()` with `FlashConnect.trace()`) it outputs

```
Start
---
```

Is that a bug, or is it FlashDevelop handling errors in a different way intentionally?

If it is the latter is there a workaround to access the stacktrace of an error?

Comment: It's really annoying, it means asunit cant tell me where my tests are failing

Comment: Are you compiling in Debug configuration?

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling in Debug configuration.

Comment: Maybe it has a problem w/multiline strings or something like that. You could try stripping them out with a regex. I don't have FlashDevelop (on a Mac) and can't find the source for `FlashConnect.trace()` -- can you add the code for that method?

Comment: It's not a problem with `FlashConnect.trace()` because it even occurs when i replace `print(stack);` with `stack.length;` or `stack[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by switching to using a dubugging version of the flash player, i hope this helps anyone else with this problem.

[instructions for specifying a debug player](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3%3aDebugging)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling in Debug configuration and you may have to enable (set True) "Verbose Stack Trace" in your Project Properties > Compiler Options

Comment: I'm running in debug and it didn't change things when i set "Verbose Stack Trace" to true. I'm more concerned about it not tracing "End" than it not tracing the stack